# Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRAuth' (Swift 2, Firebase 3.x)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, xcode7, firebase-authentication

Updating to the new firebase. Created a new signin VC and everything was working fine in terms of no errors.

Trying to replicate this new tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Now all of a sudden I'm getting the error Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRAuth' all over my VC.

I've tried re-installing the pods file and haven't had any luck, it seems that sometimes if it add "import Firebase" then remove it the app will compile, it seems there is no rhyme or reason for why it works sometimes and other times it doesn't:

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth


class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser { //error here 
        self.signedIn(user)
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapSignIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Sign In with credentials.
    let email = emailField.text
    let password = passwordField.text
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!) { //error here (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.signedIn(user!)
    }
}
@IBAction func didTapSignUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let email = emailField.text
    let password = passwordField.text
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!) { // error here(user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.setDisplayName(user!)
    }
}

func setDisplayName(user: FIRUser) {
    let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest.displayName = user.email!.componentsSeparatedByString("@")[0]
    changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion(){ (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.signedIn(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) //error here
    }
}

@IBAction func didRequestPasswordReset(sender: AnyObject) {
    let prompt = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: "Email:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in
        let userInput = prompt.textFields![0].text
        if (userInput!.isEmpty) {
            return
        }
        FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(userInput!) { //error here (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    prompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)
    prompt.addAction(okAction)
    presentViewController(prompt, animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func signedIn(user: FIRUser?) {
    MeasurementHelper.sendLoginEvent()

    AppState.sharedInstance.displayName = user?.displayName ?? user?.email
    AppState.sharedInstance.photoUrl = user?.photoURL
    AppState.sharedInstance.signedIn = true
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Constants.NotificationKeys.SignedIn, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
   // performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.Segues.SignInToFp, sender: nil)
}

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950777/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier

Comment: Thanks Anbu, just took a look at that question and my SignInViewController was already correctly connected to the target. I'm at a loss for what else the issue may be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I updated Cocoapods and ran pod update and it fixed all my issues

Comment: I need to know what commands you used. Of course it's chosen as answer, but will be great what exactly you did. It's the right thing.

Answer (score 52):

*For future readers:*

Make sure to have include the following in your `Podfile`:

`pod 'Firebase/Auth'`

After installing the pods, use:

`import FirebaseAuth`

This is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Updated 2016/12/26 with `Swift 3` and `Firebase 3.11.0`
Add to Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

In your place you need to use Auth, just

```
import Firebase
```

Clean and rebuild, you will clear error.

This solution is referred from Google.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth

Answer (score 5):

You have to add pod 'Firebase/Auth' on pod file, import Firebase and FirebaseAuth to your controller, now to use Auth isn't `FIRAuth.auth()`, is `Auth.auth().signInAnonymously` and work's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Add "import Firebase" and press cmd + B

Answer (score 3):

When using Firebase in a UIViewController I make sure to import Firebase and after that I clean the cache/build (cmd + shift + k) and then build (cmd + b).

Seems to work but I have to redo the process every time I build.

*EDIT*

If it doesn't work the first clean, just keep on cleaning until it does. Not the perfect solution but it works.

Answer (score 2):

first we need to add pod of firebase Auth in podfile

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

Then we need to run the terminal with '**pod install**'

According to the firebase Doc,we need to add ***import firebase*** on our viewcontroller .but it will not solve your problem.you need to add ***import FirebaseAuth***.This will remove the error.

Answer (score 2):

Solution now, in Swift 4.2, where it complains about simply "Auth" and not "FIRAuth" saying "Use of unresolved identifier Auth":

Note there are two distinct imports. `import Firebase` and `import FirebaseAuth`

The first was sufficient most of the time, but sometimes the compiler gets confused and adding the second version helps clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this import:

> import FirebaseAuth

Add this statement instead. This worked for me.

> import Firebase

Comment: never mind ignore this answer, I am still getting errors when i run it randomly, I clean the project and rebuild it and the error goes away. But after sometime I encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now it has been renamed from "FIRAuth" to "Auth"

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) it's now just "Auth" and not "FIRAuth"

Answer (score -3):

MeasurementHelper.sendLoginEvent()

```
AppState.sharedInstance.displayName = user?.displayName ?? user?.email
```

AppStateis an unidetified