# In Swift: How to use uislider value as a variable to set rotation speed

Tags: uislider

I have successfully printed the value of a UISlider in a label using the code below:

```
 @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    var currentValue: String = String(Int(sender.value))
    statusLabel.text = currentValue
   }
```

[Label showing UISlider value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyIqw.png)

What I want to do now is to use this value as the variable “a” in the code below which sets the duration of rotation of a sprite.

```
let rotation = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi * -1, duration: a)
    let infiniteRotation = SKAction.repeatForever(rotation)

    centerNode.run(infiniteRotation)
```

Thank You.

Comment: Duration in what? Seconds? Milliseconds? Also, what's not working? Are you asking how to pass the value to this?

Comment: Any number I use between 1 and 5 gets the results I want. I am assuming they are taken as seconds.  I did a search for "UISlider pass the value" but all the examples were for creating a label.  I want to pass the value to the "TimeInterval" marked "a" in the code above to change the speed of the rotation using the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global variable...

```
var timeAmount = 0
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
   timeAmount = Int(sender.value)
   println("Slider and timeAmount changing to \(timeAmount) ?")
}
```

and then in your function for the rotation, just use:

```
func __somefunction__(some params){

    ...

    let rotation = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi * -1, duration: timeAmount)
    let infiniteRotation = SKAction.repeatForever(rotation)
    centerNode.run(infiniteRotation)

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank You.  I ran the code, then got the error message: "Use of unresolved identifier "timeAmount".  I found the solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950777/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier

1) Right Click your MainViewController.swift

2) Select Show File Inspector

3) On Right side panel, look at Target Membership

4) Add your class to target by check the box 
It got rid of the error message, but now I get a screen with my UISlider only and nothing else.  I will do some research.  If I don't find a solution I will post it with a link to this page.  God Bless!