# Use of unresolved identifier 'ARSCNFaceGeometry'

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, xcode9, arkit

For the face geometry I have imported ARKit and SceneKit frameworks but its showing error that use of unresolved identifier

```
func createFaceGeometry() {

    // This relies on the earlier check of `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported`.
    let device = sceneView.device!
    let maskGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!
    let glassesGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!

    nodeForContentType = [
        .faceGeometry: Mask(geometry: maskGeometry),
        .overlayModel: GlassesOverlay(geometry: glassesGeometry),
        .blendShapeModel: RobotHead()
    ]
}
```

Comment: have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951431/4056108)

Comment: Are you using Xcode 9 GM? AR face tracking stuff isn’t in the Xcode 9 beta releases that were posted before iPhone X was announced. Are you building for device or for iOS Simulator? The simulator SDK doesn’t include symbols dependent on Metal (including parts of SceneKit), because Metal doesn’t work on Simulator.

Comment: have only had this problem when my x wasn't connected to my machine when having this file open.