# Referring to an audio file in Bundle, Xcode sees 'Use of unresolved identifier issue'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After reading through the (many) questions about 'use of unresolved' identifier issues ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950777/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier)), the answer typically seems to be adding a class and then ensuring it is targeted using File Inspector.

I am not trying to create a new class -- I am trying to target an MP3 file that is in the Bundle using `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
//5 -
var songPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

//6 -
func prepareSongAndSession() {

    do {
        //7 - Insert the song from our Bundle into our AVAudioPlayer
        songPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "03 Smile", ofType: "mp3")!))
```

Xcode flags the final line with: `Unresolved identifier 'Bundle'`. I don't understand why, as I understood the Bundle acts as a directory.

Finally, I thought maybe the MP3 did not copy itself into the directory when I dragged the file. After going to the root file > Build Phases, I have confirmed the file is listed in "Copy Bundle Resources."

Am I missing something?

Xcode 7.3 & Swift 2.2.

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using? Have you imported `Foundation`?

Comment: Xcode 7.3 & Swift version 2.2 (via Terminal). I am also importing `import AVFoundation` before `class ViewController: UIViewController {` in that file.

Comment: Do you know that Swift 2 is very out-of-date? You really, really need to be using Xcode 9 and Swift 4 at this point. But that aside, `URL` and `Bundle` are only available as of Swift 3. In Swift 2 you need to use `NSURL` and `NSBundle`. But do yourself a huge favor and upgrade now. You are wasting your time using Swift 2.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy -- I am getting back into it after a few years and didn't realize Swift 2 was that out of date... Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Current Apple documentation is for Swift 4.
Simply update Xcode to latest stable version and you'll be able to code according to documentation, without this error of undefined reference to `Bundle`.

Also note that Xcode 9 will be mandatory at some point of July 2018 to publish on iTunes Connect.